# Problem accessing ViewData in HTML for MVC3 Razor project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

javascript
I am passing the value "3" from a Controller into a ViewData variable to be displayed via the HTML.

I have verified that right before the ActionResult is returned, that the value "3" is in the variable (see below code):

```
public ActionResult Index()
.
.
.
ViewData["ErrCode"] = "3";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

However, the string, when rendered, is always rendered as an empty string (see below):

```
        $().customAlert();
$(document).ready(function () {
'' = "3";
var strErrCode = '';
alert('Hello!');
});
```

The above rendered code is from the following code in the  tag of the _Layout.cshtml Shared View file. Note that I am even forcing the value "3" into the "ErrCode" variable and the script gets rendered as above.

```
    $().customAlert();
    $(document).ready(function () {
             '@ViewData["ErrCode"]' = "3";
        var strErrCode = '@ViewData["ErrCode"]';
        alert('Hello!');
    });
```

I must be using the ViewData incorrectly in the js. How can I accomplish this simple feat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `RedirectToAction`. This has the effect of returning a 302 http status code pointing you at the URL of the Home action on the Index controller.

At that point, you lose whatever was in ViewData. You need to pass the value as part of the URL, for example via the query string:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { ErrCode = 3 });
```

Update: You can also use [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) instead of `ViewData`. This is a collection that persists data until the next request (and the next request only).

Comment: Ahhh, so the ViewData & ViewBag objects essentially lose their contents on a postback, just like a web form when submitted loses its data --- correct?

Comment: I will use your suggestion first thing in the morning at work and let you know how it turns out. If I'm not using a redirect, in other words just return a View, then the data will still be there --- correct?

Comment: Yes, a redirect causes the client to issue a brand new request to a given URL. Any state that existed on the server will be lost unless you persist it in some way (in the query string, session state, etc.).

Comment: You could also consider using TempData.

Comment: marcind, the ErrCode variable is still coming back as an empty string...

**Controller code**
TempData["ErrCode"] = "3";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

**_Layout.cshtml code**
alert('@TempData["ErrCode"]');

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, my mistake... I forgot to do a post... Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciat eit.

Comment: A Redirect you say will cause the ViewBag object to lose its contents once it's executed. How about an ActionResult? I've heard from other posts (regarding the same issue), that the ViewBag objects are saved for ActionResults until the page gets fully rendered. Once fully rendered, it loses its contents. This is correct?

Comment: Redirect is a type of ActionResult. Yes, once a result is executed the contents of ViewBag goes away.